# edit of select option with multiple selecting option

Tags: php, html

Facing some issue with multiple selection for  type.

In my CRM script, I am storing data for customer visit details with number of sales persons how have visited there. Here is my visit table

```
visit_id | customer | visit_date
1        | 4        | 2020-05-16
2        | 3        | 2020-05-20
```

and attended sales persons details i am storing in a table visit_attendees like this

```
id | visit_id | attendees
1  | 1        | 1
2  | 1        | 3
3  | 1        | 4
4  | 2        | 3
5  | 2        | 2
```

here attendees ids i get from table sales_persons

```
sid | fname  | lname  
1   | ABC    | CDS
2   | XYZ    | AAA
3   | ZZZ    |
4   | CDE    | H
```

storing is not an issue. But while editing, i want to these values as selected and want to store only if extra is added or already presented is removed. I am not getting how to do it.

Now i am doing right about turn method like this

```
<?php  
$m1 = DB_query("SELECT sp.id, sp.fname, sp.lname, va.attendees FROM sales_persons sp INNER JOIN visit_attendees va ON sp.id=va.attendees WHERE va.visit_id=".$VisitID.""); ?>
<h4>Attendies</h4>
<select name="attendees[]" class="form-control select2 is-invalid" multiple="multiple" required>
<?php while($m2 = DB_fetch_array($m1)) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $m2['id'];?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $m2['fname'].' '.$m2['lname'];?></option>
<?php } 
$st = "SELECT id, fname, lname FROM sales_persons";
$st1 = DB_query($st);
while($st2 = DB_fetch_array($st1)) {  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $st2['id']; ?>"> <?php echo $st2['fname'].' '.$st2['lname']; ?> </option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

and updating the table visit_attendees like this

```
if(isset($_POST['UpdateVisits']))
    {  

$vid = DB_escape_string($_POST['visit_id']);    
   $attendees = $_POST['attendees'];

//$l1 = "UPDATE visits SET ....";

$d1 = DB_query("DELETE FROM visit_attendeees WHERE visit_id=".$vid.""); 
    foreach($attendees as $attend)
{
$att =  "INSERT INTO visit_attendies(visit_id, attendees) VALUES(".$vid.", ".DB_escape_string($attend).")"; 
$att1 = DB_query($att);
}

}
```

is there any other straight method to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if you want to update your MySQL Table, but in case that you are not querying by these fields I would suggest you to save the attendees ids in a json instead of a single row for each one. That would mean you have only one row which to update and save many queries to the database.

Json is not the best option to save in MySQL but in case you are querying by id, not by attendees id that would pretty much do the trick for you.

That way you would need to save the attendees ids in array and then update them to the field like:

```
"UPDATE visit_attendies SET attendees = '".json_encode($attendies_arr)."' where visit_id = '".$vid."'"
```

And then when you select them you would do json_decode and get id of attendees.
The field should be a text field.

Comment: I am very poor in json_encode or decode, is there any other way without using json?

Comment: I suppose there is other way, although the json is not much complicated. You are encoding array and then decoding array. All the time you are working with basic php arrays. The json in the mysql is looking like a javascript array, nothing special. For example array with 3 values 3,5,7 will look like [3,5,7]. That's it. The only think is when you use json_decode($json, true) you should give true to the second parameter so it returns it as php array and not std class.